# How to get response only for a specific path/endpoint?

Tags: api, go, routes, gorilla

```
router.HandleFunc("/v1/m/mailboxes", s.handleGetAllMailboxes()).Methods(http.MethodGet)

func (s *Server) handleGetAllMailboxes() http.HandlerFunc {
  return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) { 
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(mailboxes)
  }
}
```

I'm testing the route with Postman. But whenever i hit `http://localhost/v1/m/\*`,
i get the encoded Json.

I want the API to responed only when the correct path `http://localhost/v1/m/mailboxes` is called.

Comment: Can you share the whole router file ? do you have another route start with `/v1/m`?

Answer (score 0):

Tried the following bench of code:

```
func main() {
    router := mux.NewRouter()
    router.HandleFunc("/v1/m/mailboxes", handleGetAllMailboxes()).Methods(http.MethodGet)
    http.Handle("/", router)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
func handleGetAllMailboxes() http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
        json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(`{"a": "b"}`)
    }
}
```

And I only got response on `curl http://localhost:8080/v1/m/mailboxes` and not on any other routes.
`curl http://localhost:8080/v1/m/aa` simply returns `404 page not found`.

Maybe the problem is more on how you expose your routes after the part of code that you quote.

Also, the last solution (that not really nice) is to use a matcher:

```
// Test Routes
router.HandleFunc("/v1/m/mailboxes", s.handleGetAllMailboxes()).Methods(http.MethodGet).MatcherFunc(func(r *http.Request, rm *mux.RouteMatch) bool {
    return r.URL.Path == "/v1/m/mailboxes"
})
```